# Pocketsphinx acoustic model creating issue with sphinx_fe command

Tags: ubuntu, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

Now I have some trouble with acoustic model building I use a ubuntu 14.04 on virtual box to test run pocketsphinx and train my acoustic model using sphinxtrain. Do I need to convert my .wav files to .mfc first and then run "sphinxtrain run" command? I did following steps,

1. Run "**sphinxtrain run**" command
2. Run **sphinx_fe -i Anuradha-eight.wav -o file.mfc -argfile etc/feat.params** in order to convert .wav to .mfc

Both tries failed. Output and Log files can be seen [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01951127994864765432)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to convert my .wav files to .mfc first and then run "sphinxtrain run" command? I

No

> Output and Log files can be seen HERE

```
 Failed to open /home/anuradha/Desktop/Workspace/sinhala/wav/Chathuri/chathuri-amma.wav: No such file or directory
```

Log says that the file is missing in the path it should be placed at.

Comment: But the file is their. the wav file is exist in the said location  and I'm also getting <br/> **WARNING: Error in '/home/anuradha/Desktop/Workspace/sinhala/etc/sinhala_train.fileids', the feature file '/home/anuradha/Desktop/Workspace/sinhala/feat/Anuradha/Anuradha_eight.mfc' does not exist, or is empty** <br/> and my ETC and WAV folder contents can be seen [HERE] [1] [1]: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73024785348361020085

Comment: Your files have wma extention. Files must be transcoded in WAV, the format must be 16khz 16bit mono.

Comment: And obviously files must have .wav extenion, not .wma

Comment: I have corrected the wav file mistake and ran the sphinxtrain but now I'm getting

WARN: "gauden.c", line 1349: Scaling factor too small: -885637.551544
WARN: "gauden.c", line 1349: Scaling factor too small: -5339149.160396
WARN: "gauden.c", line 1349: Scaling factor too small: -1041694.181730

ERROR: "backward.c", line 1011: alpha(2.500000e-01) <> sum of alphas * betas (0.000000e+00) in frame 113
ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: anuradha/anuradha-eight ignored

My file stracture can be seen here  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30374866907752211810

Comment: It is ok, you need more training data

Comment: what will be the minimum amount training data .For example: 200 word with 200 recordings? since I'm doing this for sinhala language before go into large scale of data, I want to test with minimum.

Comment: It is covered in tutorial in the beginning, you should just read it through